# Можно ли совместить работу на Cи c Java?

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk, native

Есть проект на чистом Си. Он выходит в сеть, что-то делает и тому подобное.

Пришли терминалы на Android. Мы хотим поместить это приложение в Терминал. В Android есть NDK, которая пускает писать код на Си, но при этом много коментов прочел, что придется писать весь ui самому на нативе.

Нельзя ли использовать проект на Си как слой дата: в Android приложении запустил какую-то функцию, на джаве спустился на уровень натива, выполнил эту функцию, передал данные в джава и отобразил на экране.

Возможно такое реализовать ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно всю логику реализовывать в C++, а в Java всю отрисовку делать.

Впрочем, можно и саму гуятину в C++ реализовать. Есть тот же [Juce](https://juce.com/) для этого.

Если проект на OpenGL, то можно вообще всё на C++/Си написать, только пару враперов на Java сделать.

Android/Java NDK позволяет обмениваться сообщениями в обе стороны: вы можете как из Си кода вызвать Java, так и из Java вызвать Си код.

Comment: Понял это супер !) код будет на Си а отрисовка на Java/ui)будет круто )спасибо

Comment: @elik да не за что, собственно (:

Comment: а не подскажешь туториалы ?

Comment: @elik их тьма. Даже я в своё время по ним уроки делал http://suvitruf.ru/2013/02/02/2982/ http://suvitruf.ru/2013/03/03/3081/osnovy-android-ndk-vyzov-java-metodov-iz-cc-koda-pri-pomoshhi-jni/ (:

Comment: если есть . еще то прошу поделитесь )

Comment: @elik я только на английском могу посоветовать вроде такого http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html

Comment: Suvitruf - Andrei Apanasik, подскажите пожалуйста, а насколько актуальны сейчас эти уроки 8 летней давности ? Можно ли их использовать в 2020 году ?

Comment: @Optimus1 концептуально мало что изменилось. Но лучше найти уроки поновее. Да на IDEA перейти с Eclipse.